# Get columns data maually

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working on a project in which I have a table with 4 columns. I want to get the last non-empty data of the every column, such as It will show

- column1 + its last non-empty data
- column2 + its last non-empty data
- column3 + its last non-empty data
- column4 + its last non-empty data

So can you explain me which code is applied to do that

[image]

Comment: Is there anything you tried yourself?

Comment: 'not null' checks the row data but I will check entire row

Comment: may be switch case work for it, now I am trying if using switch case but better to get the right query of every case

Comment: I get it statically but is there any way for dynamically and use just only one array instead of $a, $b, $c

Comment: while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
 {  
  if($row['name']!='' && $row['password']=='' && $row['username']=='' )
  { $a['name']=$row['name'];
   $a['username']=$row['username'];
   $a['password']=$row['password'];
  }
  if($row['name']=='' && $row['username']!='' && $row['password']=='')
  { $b['name']=$row['name'];
   $b['username']=$row['username'];
   $b['password']=$row['password'];   
  }
  if($row['name']=='' && $row['username']=='' && $row['password']!='')
  { $c['name']=$row['name'];
   $c['username']=$row['username'];
   $c['password']=$row['password'];
  }
 }

Comment: echo "<tr>";
  echo '<td>'.$a['name'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$a['username'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$a['password'].'</td>';
  echo "</tr>";

  echo "<tr>";
  echo '<td>'.$b['name'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$b['username'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$b['password'].'</td>';
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo '<td>'.$c['name'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$c['username'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$c['password'].'</td>';
  echo "</tr>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first create variables and then store the non-empty data in it.

```
$name = $pass = $username = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $name = (!empty($row['name'])) ? $row['name'] : $name;
    $pass = (!empty($row['password'])) ? $row['password'] : $pass;
    $username = (!empty($row['name'])) ? $row['name'] : $username;
}
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>'.$name.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$username.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$pass.'</td>';
echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I get it statically but is there any way for dynamically and use just only one array instead of $a, $b, $c

```
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {  
    if($row['name']!='' && $row['password']=='' && $row['username']=='' )
    {
        $a['name']=$row['name'];
        $a['username']=$row['username'];
        $a['password']=$row['password'];
    }
    if($row['name']=='' && $row['username']!='' && $row['password']=='')
    {
        $b['name']=$row['name'];
        $b['username']=$row['username'];
        $b['password']=$row['password'];            
    }
    if($row['name']=='' && $row['username']=='' && $row['password']!='')
    {
        $c['name']=$row['name'];
        $c['username']=$row['username'];
        $c['password']=$row['password'];
    }
}

    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>'.$a['name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$a['username'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$a['password'].'</td>';
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>'.$b['name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$b['username'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$b['password'].'</td>';
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>'.$c['name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$c['username'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$c['password'].'</td>';
    echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
$result = array(); 
$i = 0; 

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
    if($row['name']!='' || $row['password']!='' || $row['username']!='' ){
        $result[$i]['name']=$row['name'];
        $result[$i]['username']=$row['username'];
        $result[$i]['password']=$row['password'];
    }
    $i++;
 }
```